# Add Note View Controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to make a note view controller for an iphone app that gives the user the ability to add notes (in the same way that the Notes app for iphone works)

the question i have is regarding **how** i would make a NoteViewController and what i would put inside it to make it show some notes..

it does not have to be too complicated at all.. i would be a happy with a tableview and an add button that brings up a keyboard to let the keyboard write a note and then save it in the tableview..

could someone show me what i would put inside my controller to:

1. Display tableview with data (eg saved notes from previous session).
2. the **method** that the button calls (eg when the "add note" button is pressed) **how** would i get it bring up a keyboard and allow the user to add text.
3. Finally **how** and **where** would it save those notes (see 1.)

Thank you for reading and any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

So thinking in terms of the Apple notes app, I would decompose it into the following:

A SplitViewController - This would be comprised of a table view that enumerates all the notes that are saved within the app and a main view controller that is the active note.

The note view controller would be comprised of a text view for entering the note and  a toolbar at the bottom for the various functions needed to switch between notes, delete a note, or send a note.

Comment: thank you for your reply.. i do not wish for it to be that complicated.. simple add and delete functions are all that are necessary as it will eventually be part of a larger tab application..

Comment: could you by any chance direct me to some resources, as i am struggling to come up with something decent.. :(